# How to read table data using angularjs and post with update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form as given below:

```
<form name="my-test-suite" ng-submit=submit() ng-controller="createTestSuite">
        <div ng-controller="showTests">
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Select Test</th>
                            <th>Test ID#</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="test in testcases">
                            <td>
                            <input ng-model='ctrl.test.selected' type="checkbox" value="">
                            </td>
                            <td ng-model='test.id' >{{ test.id }}</td>
                            <td ng-model='test.resourceId'>{{ test.resourceId }}</td>
                            <td ng-model='test.allGraphs'>{{ test.allGraphs }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div align=center>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and controllers as:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('showTests', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:4567/config-manager/tests").then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.testcases = response.data;
            });
});

app.controller('createTestSuite', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function() {
       console.log($scope.test);
    }; 

}]);
```

It shows the grid properly with showTests but when I want to see the table data using createTestSuite Controller I cant see $scope at all. This is the problem. I want to read entire table data and use with post request. Please help.

One got below json for get request:

```
[ {
  "id" : 55,
  "allGraphs" : null,
  "resourceId" : "126"
}, {
  "id" : 56,
  "allGraphs" : null,
  "resourceId" : "125"
}, {
  "id" : 58,
  "allGraphs" : null,
  "resourceId" : "140"
} ]
```

Comment: I did  console.log($scope.testcases); and getting undefined. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `ng-repeat="test in testcases"` but you're never defining `$scope.test` so you're not able to access it.
A quick way to pass your table data from the `showTests` to the `createTestSuite` controller through `ng-click="submit(testcases)`.

Following changes would be needed:

Update the view:

```
<form name="my-test-suite" ng-controller="createTestSuite">
    // Other things stay the same
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit(testcases)" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Update controller:

```
app.controller('createTestSuite', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       // Filter through the selected items if needed
    }; 

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) Now I have to convert that into JSON and post it to diff. URL.

Comment: worked like a charm :) 
app.controller('createTestSuite', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
 var updatedSuite;
    $scope.submit = function(data) {
       updatedSuite =  angular.toJson(data);
       console.log(updatedSuite);
    }; 

}]);